# copy blob hibernate version 4.2.3.Final vs. 4.1.7.Final

Tags: oracle, hibernate, blob

Does anyone know hibernate version 4.2.3.Final change the way of version 4.1.7.Final copying blob?

Here is what I am running into trouble with 4.2.3.Final.

Environment: Hibernate 4.2.3.Final and Oracle Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.3) JDBC Driver

Scenario:

The entity manager and a blob are defined in an entity class as:

```
public class Attachment {
    ...
    @PersistenceContext transiet EntityManager em;
    ...
    @Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @Column (insertable=true,updatable=false,name="document")
    @Blob 
    private Blob document;
    ...
    public InputStream getDocument() { return doc.getBinaryStream(); }

    public void setDocument(InputStream is) { 
        Session hibnernateSession=(Session)em.getDelegate(); 
        LobCreator creator=Hibernate.getLobCreator(hibernateSession); 
        this.document=createBlob(is, is.available()); 
    }
    ...
}
```

Say I have an instance called oldAttachment fetched from the database,then I create another new instance called newAttachment.

When I want to copy a blob data from oldAttachment to newAttachment, under hibernate 4.1.7.Final, I can just simply do as:

```
newAttachment.setDocument( oldAttachment.getDocument() );
```

then save the newAttachment to the database and it works perfectly.

Now under hibernate 4.2.3.Final, if I do the way as shown above, I will get the oracle error,
which will complain that I give a NULL value.

In other words, the hibernate does not read the blob stream data out from the oldAttachment and then put data into the newAttachment for me.

Instead, it requires me (API user) do the actual copying stream thing.

In order to copy a blob from one the other, I have do something like:

```
{
  ...
  BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(  oldAttachment.getDocument() );
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  byte[] data = new byte[4096];
  int len = 0;
  while( (len=bin.read(data, 0, data.length) != -1 ) {
     baos.write(data, 0, len);
  }
  baos.flush();
  ByteArrayInputStream foo = new ByteArrayInputStream( baos.toByteArray() );
  // then call
  newAttachment.setDocument( foo );
  // then call save newAttachment to database etc.....
  ...
}
```

So I am wondering if it is a bug in hibernate's BlobProxy or a feature of hibernate 4.2.3.Final.

Many many thanks if someone can explain to me why hibernate changed the copy blob behavior as it used to be.

Comment: Possibly your call to `is.available()` is the problem. It returns the likely number of bytes currently available without doing any real I/O operation. Thus it most likely returns 0. It doesn't return the length as would be required in your case.

Comment: So the problem is still as that hibernate 4.2.3.Final requires the user to do the actual I/O operation.   In 4.1.7.Final even you give a 0 length, hibernate will do the real I/O operation for you.